# CSS column-count has different behavior in fire fox and chrome.

Tags: html, css

I want to display the div's like a bricks. I have tried with column-count property and it is working fine in fire fox but not in chrome.

```
.container {
   column-count: 3;
   column-gap: 1em;
}
.block {
   width: 100%;
   border: 1px solid;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: justify;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Please see the below example
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jze74n6b/3/)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to flex the container:

```
.container
{
    display:flex;
}
```

will give you the 3 columns you need, see:

```css
.container {
  column-count: 3;
  display:flex;
}
.block {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
  <div class="block">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't `column-count` redundant after this layout change?

Comment: Indeed @IlyaStreltsyn

Answer (score 0):

.block {} remove inline-block. add -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ for chrome support line. Then set equal height to all divs. (or) Use display flex.

```css
.container {
   -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
 column-count: 3;
 -webkit-column-gap:1em;
 -moz-column-gap:1em;
 column-gap:1em;
}
.block {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
  <div class="block">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Vimal check my answer. if any doubt let me know.